# Why can't I use my View Controller as a property?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

for some reason I get an error here

```
#import "OtherViewController.h"

@interface ViewController: UIViewController



@property (nonatomic, strong) OtherViewController *otherViewController;
```

this gives me an error saying 'unknown type name OtherViewController' why is this happening to me? Is this not the way to send messages to other view controllers. If so what is the way you are supposed to do this?

Comment: Are you sure there is no spelling mistake in there? Do you get any other compile errors, especially in the included header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have posted, there isn't anything wrong with what you have posted.  That being said, you don't need to declare a property for the other VC.  What you need to do is declare a public property on OtherViewController (like an NSString) and then you can access that property from the ViewController class.  Something like (assuming you are using Storyboards):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegueID"]) {
         OtherViewController *ovc = segue.destinationViewController;
         ovc.myPublicNSStringProperty = @"Something";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the header in the .m file

```
#import "OtherViewController.h"
```

and in the header .h file add

```
@class OtherViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't know for sure since there's not enough info given, but I've seen similar errors if you have circular imports. That is, if OtherViewController.h includes #import ViewController.

So, you could try using @class in one of them to avoid the circular references:

```
@class OtherViewController;
```

The, be sure to include in your ViewController.m:

```
#import "OtherViewController.h"
```